# Mat checkbox custom and specific colors

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have two mat checkboxes and I'm trying to change the color of each one, one green and the other one
red, but what I have found changes both colors and I tried to change them by adding a class, but didnt work, here is the code:

```
   <div class="half right">
            <mat-checkbox color="" class="entradaCheck">Coming</mat-checkbox>

            <mat-checkbox color="primary" class="salidaCheck">Exit</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
```

the css

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(15, 91, 33) !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox:not(.mat-checkbox-disabled) .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: rgb(15, 91, 33) !important;
}
```

what I did tried

```
.entradaCheck::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(15, 91, 33) !important; }

.entradaCheck::ng-deep .mat-checkbox:not(.mat-checkbox-disabled) .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: rgb(15, 91, 33) !important; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise against using ::ng-deep since it's deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-j8ufpw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fmain.ts

You should be able to apply the styles for the classes in your root sstyles.scss (src/app/styles.scss) as follows:

```
mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox-checked {
  &.entradaCheck .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(15,91,33) !important;
  }
}
```

If using styles.css:

```
mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox-checked.entradaCheck .mat-checkbox-background{
    background-color: rgb(15,91,33) !important;
}
```

Comment: I am using angular 13 and css, I must use ::ng-deep even that it is deprecated, because if I dont, it doesnt work, and I cant use what your code because of the css, I just want to figure out how to modify differents components with the same class and tag of angular material but with different styles for each one, thanks for your answer

Comment: "I cant use your code because of the css" - could you elaborate on that? Is your global stylesheet .css rather than .scss? If that is the case, I can modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I will look deep for the ::ng-deep deprecated, or do you know what I can use instead of ::ng-deep on css?

Comment: Thanks, that is right, I am usign css instead of scss ("because of my mates say to :(")

Comment: still not working

Comment: I made a mistake in the css; I'd forgotten to include .mat-checkbox-background. I've updated the code and added a stackblitz example. It uses scss but you should be able to translate it to css to work using that pattern.

Comment: I'm glad we got it working! Have fun out there.